# Restore Blender custom settings after loading Factory Settings?

Tags: settings

I'm working with the Blender folks to resolve an issue and because I have a lot of add-ons they would like me to go to File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings. I'm happy to do that, but how do I then restore my custom settings at a later time?

I've looked around and can't find any information on this. Thanks. Blender 3.5, Windows 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a backup of your user preferences folder. It's in `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\`(You can copy-paste that into Windows run menu(<kbd>WinLogo</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) or file explorer's address bar). Full path is usually `C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender`, but AppData folder is hidden by default in Windows. There should be folders for whatever versions of Blender you have installed. It's not a bad idea to have a backup of that in any case. So if you accidently save preferences, or have Auto-Save Preferences enabled after loading factory settings you can delete that folder and replace it with your backup.

[image]

Disabling Auto-Save Preferences might be a good idea if you often need Blender with factory settings. I do recommend having a backup in any case.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)